# confusion matrix report accuracy problem jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter

I want to plot a confusion matrix to visualize the classifer's performance, but it accuracy and recall does not show

**Accuracy Screenshot**

[image: Accuracy]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any data here, or any code either.  Anyway, this works for me.

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=30,
                           n_informative=12,
                           n_clusters_per_class=1, n_classes=10,
                           class_sep=2.0, random_state=42)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.3, stratify=y)

clf = LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000, random_state=42).fit(X_train, y_train)

df = pd.DataFrame(classification_report(clf.predict(X_test), 
                                        y_test, digits=2,
                                        output_dict=True)).T

df['support'] = df.support.apply(int)

df.style.background_gradient(cmap='viridis',subset=pd.IndexSlice['0':'9', :'f1-score'])

import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(df, annot=True)
```

[image]